# Python - How to change dictionary value dynamically

Tags: python, dictionary

I am trying to use a dictionary in such a way so that it returns a value dynamically. The following code should print "hello" first, then "world". As of now, it prints "hello" two times. Is there a way for me to use this dictionary dynamically?

```
val = "hello"
test = {
  "A" : val
}
print(test["A"])
val="world"
print(test["A"])
```

Comment: I can't understand what you're trying to achieve here. Could you please more specific and provide a more useful example?

Comment: What you are asking isn't really possible in Python and hints at a lack of understanding about the difference between names like `var` and values like `"world"`.  It sounds like you should step back and think about the way you are modeling your data in the program. Having magical side effects, like a dict value changing when a variable is redefined, seems like a terrible plan to me. But it's hard to say more given the simplified example that doesn't illustrate the real problem you are trying to solve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am thinking that this is not correct use of dictionaries. Could you please the whole task?

You can also check values and change the dictionary value

```
val = "hello"
test = {
  "A" : val
}
print(test["A"])
val="world"
if test["A"]!=val: test["A"]=val
print(test["A"])
```

Comment: The task is a little more complicated. To put it simply, I have a class `Frame()` that has `variables[]` in it. There is a global frame `GF`, a temporary frame `TF`, and a stack of local frames `LF_Stack`. Then, I have a class `Variable` with a string attribute `frame` (which can be "GF", "TF", "LF"). According to this attribute, I need to append this variable to the list of variables in the frame of the variable. I used the dictionary to do this (it works, when the first to values were GF, TF (which reference the objects), but `LF_Stack.frames[-1]`) did not work.

Comment: Yeah, that task is not so easy! You can try to use some tricky things: use list of lists, where inner list will be a pair. Or use only variables. Don't put it in dictionary.  Try to simplify the task by not using classes yet. Transform the task so that the user enters data directly.

Answer (score 1):

instead of `val="world"` use `test["A"] = "world"`

Comment: Yes, that is possible in the example I provided. My code, though, is larger, and the variable "val" can change on numerous places in the code and it would be unwieldy to add this line to every possible place.

Answer (score 0):

`val = "world"` assigns a new string to the variable, but doesn't change the existing string. The dictionary `test` however keeps the old string value, not a reference to the `val` variable. You need to use another mutable data structure if you want to update the dictionary like this. Just for illustration, I show how a list would work:

```py
val = ["hello"]
test = { "A" : val }
print(test["A"][0])
val[0] = "world"
print(test["A"][0])
```

Unlike a string, a list can be updated. `test` keeps the same (list) value as `val` (there is only one list in this example), but `val` is changed internally.

Note that you must not use `val = ["world"]`, as this would again just assign a new list to `val`, but leave `test` unchanged, i.e. still refer to the old list containing `"hello"`.